# Drag and drop option in ubuntu 13.04 not working

Tags: 13.04, workspace-switcher

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 32bit. I have a problem in dragging a file and opening in some application. Suppose I have to open a text file, when I try to drag the file to open in gedit, alt+tab vanishes, and I cant open gedit to open the file

Comment: can you please re-explain; I don't understand you. what does the workspace switcher and alt+tab have to do with dragging files?

Answer (score 0):

try with this, work with files and text:

1. Start dragging the text
2. Press and hold Super (windows key) + Tab (do not release the mouse button)
3. Hold Super and press Tab as many time you need to choose your text window destination
4. Release Super when you have selected the correct window
5. Release mouse button to drop the text